# 3 Speed Front Derailleur can't reach small gear

Tags: derailleur, parts, shifting, campagnolo

I bought a new frame and put my old Campagnolo Racing T components on it.
The seat tube has a diameter of 35mm and I use the Campagnolo 35mm clamp for the Racing T derailleur.

The problem is the derailleur can't push the chain to the small gear because a part of the derailleur touches the seat tube.

Is the frame incompatible with a 3 speed crank or do I just need a compatible derailleur for frames with a wider seat tube, maybe the ATHENA Tripple?

**Parts**

- Frame: BULLS Desert Falcon, Seat Tube 35mm
- Crank: Campagnolo Athena 11s
- Derailleur: Campagnolo Racing T
- Bottom Bracket: Campagnolo BB90 Power Torque

**Images:**

- Derailleur touching the frame: [image: Derailleur touching the frame]
- Crank: [image: Crank]

Comment: I've never done it but I would think some type of spacer between the chainring and the BB could give you a bit more clearance to let the front derailleur push in further.

Comment: I was thinking this too, or maybe twisting the derailleur a little to knock the chain earlier? The top picture looks like it is slightly twisted out compared to the outer sprocket, but can't tell for sure.

Comment: The BB does not have enough offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the Racing T derailleur with the Athena 11s derailleur fixed the issue.
The racing T derailleur seams to don't work with the 35mm Campagnolo clamp. Or generally don't work with frames wider than 28mm.

Answer (score 2):

The chainwheel does not sit at the correct `chain line` is the answer.

The most common cause is that you have an axle length shorter/longer than the ideal `chain line`. In this case, you have a shorter axle length.

Did you add another chainring into your crankset? If the answer is yes, you will need to tweak around: either adding spacer (not recommended) or find a compatible front derailleurs (better get to the LBS for trial/error fitting).
If the answer is no, then it will be the frame that cause you the problems, albeit unlikely. I always solve this problems by finding a correct axle length for my crankset.

You can refer to this article for more information, from Lord Sheldon.
http://www.sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html